On the analogy between rational functions and p-adic numbers
I have just learnt the concepts of rational functions and local parameters on an affine algebraic curve, and I could not help noticing that these concepts has something analogue to the theory of $p$-adic numbers in number theory in the following senses:

Given any nonsingular point $P$ on some irreducible curve, there is a local parameter $t$ vanishing at $P$ such that any rational function $u$, not identically $0$ on the curve, can be decomposed as $u = t^k v$, where $v$ is regular at $P$ and $v(P) \neq 0$.
Similarly, any nonzero $p$-adic number $\xi\in O_p$ can be decomposed as $\xi = p^l \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a unit in $O_p$.

In the decompositions above, the local parameter $t$ seems to play a role similar to $p$, in the sense that the exponent $k$ 'measures' the multiplicity of the zero of $u$ at $P$, while the exponent $l$ also 'measures' the multiplicity of $p$ in $\xi$. Besides, $p$ can also be seen as 'zero' in $O_p$, since if we write $\xi$ as a sequence $\{\xi \mod p^{i+1}: i = 0, 1, \dots\}$, then the first nonzero term in the sequence is exactly $(\xi \mod p^{l+1})$.

Two different local parameter $t, t'$ must satisfy $t = t'w$ for some regular function $w$ with $w(P) \neq 0$. This makes me feel that regular functions play a role similar to units in a UFD.

Both decompositions are 'local' properties.


Can anyone please explain the analogies above to me? I wonder whether the analogies are only coincidences? Maybe the analogies arises from a common (while relatively trivial) algebraic structures, or there are some deeper links behind these concepts?
Also, there seems to be something similar between this local decomposition of rational functions and the theory of separability of fields, but I am not sure. To be precise, after dividing $u$ by $t$ a finite number of times, one always gets $v$ with $v(P) \neq 0$, regardless of whether $u(P) = 0$. This reminds me of the well-known result in field theory that every irreducible polynomial $f\in k[X]$ (separable or not) can be represented as $f = g(X^{p^n})$ for some separable polynomial $g \in k[X]$.
I will be deeply appreciate if anyone can give me a detailed explanation.

Hello. Everything boils down to the fact that the local ring of $x$ is a discrete valuation ring (because $x$ is smooth, you can check that $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is regular and has dimension $1$, where $X$ is the curve).

@NaNoS This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

@NaNoS Thank you. So actually I should have added a tag 'commutative-algebra' ;) I am not familiar with these topics in commutative algebra, but I do agree the fact that the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and the ring of $p$-adic integers $O_p$ shares a common algebraic structure may explain the first three similarities. Still, the last point (that is, both decompositions are 'local' properties) makes me wonder whether there is a bigger common structure shared by the field of all rational functions (defined on the whole curve) and $\mathbb{Q}$, which helps explain these local-global phenomena.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you for the information. I did not write my comment as an answer because the op asked for a complete answer. I will however execute.

The majority of the algebraic content of my message can be found in "classical" books of commutative algebra like :

[AM] : « Introduction to Commutative Algebra », M.F. Atiyah and I.G. MacDonald ;
[M] : « Commutative ring theory » or « Commutative Algebra », H. Matsumura ;
[R] : « Undergraduate commutative algebra », M. Reid.

$~$From chapters 9 and 11 of [AM], we know that the regular local rings of dimension $1$ are precisely the discrete valuation rings (DVRs). Denote by $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ any $k$-algebraic curve where $k$ is any algebraically closed field and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ the local ring of regular functions of $X$ at a point $x \in X$. Because $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \operatorname{codim}_X \overline{\{x\}}$ for every $x \in X$ and every point of a $k$-variety is closed, you get $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = 1$. If $x$ is smooth, then this local ring is regular and it is a DVR with valuation $\nu_x$. A local parameter is any element $t$ in the local ring such that $\nu_x(t) = 1$. Thanks to the usual properties defining a discrete valuation, you can show that two local parameters differ by a unit (i.e. if $t'$ is a local parameter, there exists a unit $u$ such that $t' = ut$).
$~$This local parameter in our case plays the role of those regular functions at $x$ that vanish at the point with order $1$ and the valuation $\nu_x$ is a measure of the order of vanishing of a function at $x$. In analogy with polynomials or holomorphic functions, every (locally) regular functions $f$ at $x$ should be decomposed as $f = t^{\nu_x(f)} g$ where $\nu_x(g) = 0$ so that $g$ is a unit in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. The discrete valuation ring structure is perfect to reflect this analogy because $(t) = \mathfrak m = \{h \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x} ~;~ \nu_x(h) = 1\}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ and every non-zero ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a (positive) power of $\mathfrak m$ (see [AM], Proposition 9.2). In particular, for every $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, there exists $n \geq 0$ such that $(f) = \mathfrak m^n = (t^n)$ and $n = \nu_x(f)$.
$~$I'm pretty sure that now you can see how to adapt everything to the $p$-adic integers because the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ is a discrete valuation ring, so everything I wrote above is transferred without change to this ring.
